# COM Classes CLSID

Tags: uuid

Would malware ever create a CLSID or would they just use them? This question is derived from studying COM objects. So an Adobe exploit would have an Adobe CLSID in it. Does malware ever create a CLSID to function or integrate with the computer? Does malware just use a dll they injected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible.

A CLSID can be created with `guidgen.exe`.

It can specify the CLSID by placing a Guid attribute on a class.

Then it can be registered with `regasm.exe` the COM class object and use the .dll from there on.